# $http.post request not working in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, http, post

This question has been answered severeal time on this site but none of them are helping. So I ask again:

When I make a POST request like this :

```
var sectionTypeVM = new Object();
        sectionTypeVM.SectionTypeId = 0;
        sectionTypeVM.Name = $scope.message;
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://mtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/sectiontype',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: sectionTypeVM,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }).error(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

it works perfectly fine, but when I try to do something like this:

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://mtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/sectiontype',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $scope.message,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }).error(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

it doesn't. Why I need to create a separate object the javascript way and send it, why my angularJS object cannot be posted directly (they look same ) ? Is it a server side error or what ? A explanation will be helpful.

Comment: Is there an error in javascript side?

Comment: nopes. server simply returns false. on console its either error 500 or sometimes error from 200 series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between your 2 posts is that the first sends back an object with two fields (Name and SectionTypeId), while the second only sends back the contents of $scope.message. <s>I could be wrong, but it looks like $scope.message is a string. However, you are setting the content-type to application/json.</s>

The difference between the two is the first post sends this *object*:

```
{
    SectionTypeId: 0,
    Name: [
        {"name"="abc", "id"="1"},
        {"name"="bcd", "id"="2"}
    ]
}
```

While the second post sends this *array*:

```
[
    {"name"="abc", "id"="1"},
    {"name"="bcd", "id"="2"}
]
```

You need to either restructure your code so that $scope.message is a valid json object that your server accepts or wrap $scope.message in an object like your first example.

Comment: $scope.message looks like this = [{"name"="abc", "id"="1"},{"name"="bcd", "id"="2"}], so isn't it JSON enough ? infact if I print the object from code sample 1 , it looks exactly like my $scope.message. also do i need to do "data|JSon" to make it work ?

Comment: so if this is the case, 2nd one should also work. but it doesnot, that's my issue ?

Comment: I modified my answer and I hope it explains why you are getting the error. While there is nothing wrong with sending an array in a post, I believe your server is expecting an object instead

Answer (score 2):

The first is sending `sectionTypeVM` which is a JavaScript object, the second is sending `$scope.message` which, I'm presuming is a string assigned from `sectionTypeVM.Name`. The two are not identical.

Although `var sectionTypeVM = new Object()` is the same as `var sectionTypeVM = {}` in this simple example, the latter more clearly demonstrates the intent that sectionTypeVM is an object literal. Since you are sending JSON to the server, the object literal notation should be preferred.

I am assuming $scope.message is just a string (or an array). The reason the second example does not work is likely because $scope.message is not an object literal, and you have specified `json` as the expected data format. Object literals must follow the format:

```
var sectionTypeVM = {
      property: 'foo',
      property: 'bar'
};
```

If you wanted to modify your second example so that it works, you could change your data payload to object literal notation:

```
   $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://mtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/sectiontype',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { Name: $scope.message },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
    })
```

Comment: But both of them should work , shouldnt they ? or is it a server issue. arent they both sending json object ?
in respect to What you updated afterwards, $scope.message should work then. Because it is a json object.

Comment: Correct. They are the same for simple objects.

Comment: I Just want to know that,if both of them are correct, depending on what my server is expecting  ? is it ?

Answer (score 1):

If your server accpets first request you can post like this

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://mtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/sectiontype',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {SectionTypeId:0, Name: $scope.message},
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }).error(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: $scope.message has both id and name in it like this : [{"name"="abc", "id"="1"},{"name"="bcd", "id"="2"}], so can't I just do, 
data:{$scope.message}; ?

Comment: i did, earlier it want accepting either of them. my main issue is, if both of them are json enough why is one working and other not. ?

Comment: I Just want to know that,if both of them are correct, depending on what my server is expecting .

Comment: because your data is compatible with only one of server side object that your server accepts. 
i.e. if your server accepts List<string> messages = ParseStringList(jsonData); and if your code could not parse data to another object like Dictionary<int, string> messages = ParseStringList(jsonData); it gives a server side error.

Comment: my point is : $scope.message and sectionTypeVm, both are exactly same upon printing, nut server is accepting a javascript object and not my angularJS one. Why ? A server side configuration ?

Comment: is it because api is expecting object with ID and my JavaScript full fills that and not my angular object. ?

Comment: if your message object is {"name"="abc", "id"="1"}, it's not valid JSON Object. use {"name":"abc", "id":"1"} instead of {"name"="abc", "id"="1"}